# Write Rows from DataTable to Text File

Tags: c#, datatable

```
public void GenerateDetailFile()
{
  if (!Directory.Exists(AppVars.IntegrationFilesLocation))
  {
    Directory.CreateDirectory(AppVars.IntegrationFilesLocation);
  }

  DateTime DateTime = DateTime.Now;
  using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(AppVars.IntegrationFilesLocation +
                                DateTime.ToString(DateFormat) + " Detail.txt"))
  {
    DataTable table = Database.GetDetailTXTFileData();

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
      sw.WriteLine(row);
    }
  }
}
```

Not sure what I'm missing here but I think it might be the column name which I'm not sure how to set it up.

This is working fine, except, when it writes to the text file, it's writing this:

System.Data.DataRow
System.Data.DataRow
System.Data.DataRow
System.Data.DataRow
System.Data.DataRow
System.Data.DataRow
System.Data.DataRow
System.Data.DataRow
System.Data.DataRow
System.Data.DataRow

Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Something like sw.WriteLine(row["columnname"].ToString()); would be more appropriate.

Comment: writeLine(row[0].tostring()) worked fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like:

```
sw.WriteLine(row["columnname"].ToString());
```

would be more appropriate.

Comment: why it gives last row as empty new line?

Comment: @pythongbs I'd have to see the data in the table (and maybe know which database you're using, etc) to be able to answer that

Answer (score 19):

When you try to print out a `DataRow` like that, it is calling [`Object.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx), which simply prints out the name of the type.  What you want to do is something like:

```
sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", row.ItemArray));
```

This will print a comma separated list of all of the items in the `DataRow`.

Answer (score 5):

The below code will let you to write text file each column separated by '|'

```
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
      {  
         object[] array = row.ItemArray;
         for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
         {
           swExtLogFile.Write(array[i].ToString() + " | ");
         }
          swExtLogFile.WriteLine(array[array.Length - 1].ToString());             
     }
```

[Reference link](https://www.fourthbottle.com/2015/08/write-datatable-to-text-file-using-csharp-.Net.html)

Comment: Fixes: Line 4 "i =" should be "int i =",  Line 8 "array[i]" should be "array[array.Length-1]"

Answer (score 4):

There is no "natural" string representation for a DataRow. You need to write it out in whatever format you desire, i.e., comma-separated list of values, etc. You can enumerate the columns and print their values, for instance:

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    bool firstCol = true;
    foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
    {
        if (!firstCol) sw.Write(", ");
        sw.Write(row[col].ToString());
        firstCol = false;
    }
    sw.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Aren't you going to have the same problem with each `row[col]`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Not anymore :)  Although I think doing `sw.Write(row[col]` does work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the columns from each DataRow. Currently you are writing the DataRow object that is dataRow.ToString() hence you get string name `"System.Data.DataRow"` of dataRow in your file

```
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
 foreach(DataColumn column in table.Columns)
 {
  sw.WriteLine(row[column]);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**To write the DataTable rows to text files in the specific directory**

```
            var dir = @"D:\New folder\log";  // folder location

            if (!Directory.Exists(dir))  // if it doesn't exist, create
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    result.Append(row[i].ToString());
                    result.Append(i == dt.Columns.Count - 1 ? "\n" : ",");
                }
                result.AppendLine();
            }
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, "item.txt");
            StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter(path, false);
            objWriter.WriteLine(result.ToString());
            objWriter.Close();
```

Comment: Hi, What is result in this ? string builder ?

Comment: What is "result"?