# How do I write a formatted DataTable to a file, without XML?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable (dt) which, when I put into a DataGridView, is automatically and nicely formatted.

How can I "write" this table/view to a txt file? Without looping through and doing all the formatting myself.

Is there any built-in functionality?

```
dt.WriteXml(report,XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
```

The above unfortunately gives all the XML structure and tags.

I would like some similar to the "GridView".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749812/write-rows-from-datatable-to-text-file and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398019/how-to-convert-datatable-to-json-in-c-sharp  would go into that direction but in both you iterate through things

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exporting datagridview to csv file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943787/exporting-datagridview-to-csv-file)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Adam Rakaska's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26259909/1506454) (from [Exporting datagridview to csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943787/exporting-datagridview-to-csv-file)):

Just need to change format to "Text":

```
dataGridView1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText;
dataGridView1.SelectAll();
Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent());
report.WriteLine( Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text));
```

This saves having to code all the formatting oneself.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any built-in functionality?

NO, there is no built-in functionality

This will probably do the trick for you

```
public static void DataTable2TXT(DataTable dt, string fp)
{
    int i = 0;
    StreamWriter sw = null;
    sw = new StreamWriter(fp, false);
    for (i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        sw.Write(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + ";");
    }
    sw.Write(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName);
    sw.WriteLine();

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        object[] array = row.ItemArray;
        for (i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            sw.Write(array[i].ToString() + ";");
        }
        sw.Write(array[i].ToString());
        sw.WriteLine();
    }
    sw.Close();
}
```